# Node dev1@192.168.1.11 is not reachable

Tags: riak

First, I followed exactly "The Riak Fast Track" tutorial to build a four nodes Riak cluster.

Then, I changed the 127.0.0.1 IP to 192.168.1.11 in dev[1-4]/etc/app.config files, and reinstalled clusters(delete dev[1-4], fresh install).

but Riak tells me:
`Node dev1@192.168.1.11 is not reachable` when I issue `dev2/bin/riak-admin cluster join dev1@192.168.1.11`

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you also update `dev[1-4]/etc/vm.args` with the node names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 to what Brian Roach said in the comment.
Make sure to update the node name and IP address in both the app.config files AND the vm.args, before you start up the node.

Make sure node dev1 is up and reachable, before issuing a cluster join command to dev2.

Meaning, make sure dev1/bin/riak ping returns a 'pong', etc.

Comment: With Riak 2.1.4 is it required to update these files or just riak.conf is enough ?

Comment: @Raghuveer - I think just riak.conf is enough, for riak versions 2+